# "No such app" for my application when using custom domain. Works with Heroku's given URL

Tags: app, heroku

My app: `dukagjin.herokuapp.com` works just fine when using the Heroku given URL to access it. However, the custom domain that I've attached to this app does not work:

http://www.dukagj.in

The domain name is from name.com. I have created a `CNAME` record there which looks like this:

```
CNAME www.dukagj.in dukagjin.herokuapp.com 300 N/A
```

I would also like to avoid the `www.` altogether, but I don't know how to do that without messing up my emails (which I have to set up soon).

Why is my domain saying "**No such app**" when clearly the app exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like that CNAME record has propagated. I'm still seeing an A-record (which is not supported for Heroku custom domains):

```
➜  ~ dig +noall +answer www.dukagj.in
www.dukagj.in.      10  IN  A   198.105.244.23
www.dukagj.in.      10  IN  A   198.105.254.23
```

Once it does, you can view this doc for how to set up an Apex domain (no www) using an ALIAS or ANAME record: [Custom Domain Names for Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)